# Convert below C# dynamic data context registration code to VB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

```
        model.RegisterContext(typeof(NorthwindDataContext), new ContextConfiguration()
    {
        ScaffoldAllTables = true,
        MetadataProviderFactory = (type => new DefaultTypeDescriptionProvider(type, new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type)))
    });
```

In particular the MetadataProviderFactory Line... I can't quite seem to figure out how it should look in VB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MetadataProviderFactory = Function(type) new DefaultTypeDescriptionProvider(
    type, new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MetadataProviderFactory = Function (type) New DefaultTypeDescriptionProvider(
    type, New AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're looking for something like this:

```
model.RegisterContext(GetType(NorthwindDataContext), 
    New ContextConfiguration() With
    {
        .ScaffoldAllTables = True,
        .MetadataProviderFactory = Function(type) _
            New DefaultTypeDescriptionProvider(
                type, 
                New AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type))
    })
```